# R Redshift dbExistTable dbWriteTable

Tags: r, schema, amazon-redshift

I am having issues working with the schemas in Redshift connecting using R.

```
url <- "jdbc:url:port/database?user=X123&password=fakepassword"
conn <- dbConnect(driver, url)
```

so I connect fine, and when I list tables I notice the default schema is public, but I don't want to work with that schema, how do I switch schemas ?

say if it is:   lab_space

when I try this, it still lists tables in public:

```
dbListTables(conn, schema='lab_space')
```

tried this and I get an error:

```
SET search_path = lab_space;

> SET search_path = 'cust_usr';
Error: unexpected symbol in "SET search_path"
```

I must be doing something wrong ?

When I try to say check for a table and delete:

```
droptable <- dbSendQuery(conn, "drop table if exists lab_space.Tablebla")
```

it will drop it, but still give me an error:

```
Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for ",  : 
  Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for drop table if exists lab_space.Tablebla ([JDBC Driver]com.amazon.dsi.dataengine.impl.DSISimpleRowCountResult cannot be cast to com.amazon.dsi.dataengine.interfaces.IResultSet)
```

Comment: In redshift, you can set the search path with `set search_path to base` (no equals)

    dbSendQuery(con,"set search_path to base");

Answer (score 1):

You can change the schema using `dbSendUpdate` to change the `search_path` for the connection:

```
dbSendUpdate(jdbc_con,"set search_path to my_schema")
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, on this one I went with this driver

```
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
```

and then things worked with no stupid warnings errors, I guess R and Redshift still has a lot of growing up to do, not sure :- )

Answer (score -1):

In redshift, you can set the search path with `set search_path to <schema_name>` (no equals) 
`dbSendQuery(con,"set search_path to <schema_name>");`

You may assign dbSendQuery() result to var if underlying sql returns a resultset. Here drop query doesn't return any result set Object. Try without assigning to any var.

```
 dbSendQuery(conn, "drop table if exists lab_space.Tablebla")
```

Comment: I tried what you recommended, all errors, doesn't work:  > dbSendQuery(conn,"set search_path to cust_usr")
Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for ",  : 
  Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for set search_path to cust_usr ([JDBC Driver]com.amazon.dsi.dataengine.impl.DSISimpleRowCountResult cannot be cast to com.amazon.dsi.dataengine.interfaces.IResultSet)

Comment: I get a similar error for the drop table.  It drops the table, but errors out.

Comment: for the switch schema, it also works but errors out.  Later when I list the tables, it lists them from the correct schema, the errors are very annoying, I am trying to figure out why ?

Comment: Which packages you are loading for creating driver ? Can you post the driver details ?

Comment: hi this is what I am using for the driver: library(RJDBC)

# driver I am using 
download.file('http://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-downloads/drivers/RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.1.1001.jar','RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.1.1001.jar')

# connect to Amazon Redshift
driver <- JDBC("com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver", "RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.1.1001.jar", identifier.quote="`")